# Where can I find definition of struct proc_dir_entry

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am recently trying to write a linux kernel modules.

I need to create a proc file.

According to online linux cross reference file, proc_dir_entry should be in fs/proc/internal.h.

However my Ubuntu 14.04 gives me 'no such file or directory'

uname -r:

```
3.13.0-29-generic
```

Comment: Yes, that's [exactly where it is](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/internal.h?v=3.13#L32).  Do you have the kernel sources untarred in front of you? Why are you trying to use this "internal" structure anyway?

Comment: I need to pass pointer to this struct to proc_create(). However I need to dereference the pointer to initialize the structure. such operation gives me 'dereference to incomplete type'

Comment: Show your code. There is a forward declaration for `proc_dir_entry` in [`<linux/proc_fs.h>`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/proc_fs.h?v=3.13#L30) - you shouldn't need to know the actual definition of it, as you shouldn't have to initialize any of its members.

Comment: For example, see this example in [`vmstat.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/vmstat.c?v=3.13#L1303). They're passing `NULL` for `parent`, because they want their entries at the root of `/proc`.  Again, show the relevant part of your code.

Comment: I think I can self-answer my question now. like you said we don't need to know the actual definition. All I need is to setup the file_operation struct which is defined in fs.h. I was misled by this article http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html#AEN708

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the kernel header package

```
  sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: yeah, I've checked the version of linux header package. I manually added struct definition to pass the compiliation. I think there got to be another way